# How do I set internet permissions for a "command line" C program in Android?

Tags: android, c, sockets, android-ndk, android-manifest

I basically took this https://code.google.com/p/android-fb2png/ (to have something that builds plain C for Android) and put a tcp client in `main.c` that uses the usual *NIX `sys/socket.h` stuff to connect to a local network address `192.168.1.xxx:3000` and send `"hello world"`.

I've built the program and put it on my phone using `adb push`. When I run it as root using `adb shell` I get the `Connection refused` error. My tcp server on `192.168.1.xxx:3000` is running and both, the computer and the phone are connected to the same WiFi network.

I assume that this is Android blocking my program from accessing the network. The problem is that this is not an "App" and has no Java code or android manifest. Also, this program will not be ever distributed - I'm just trying things out.

While I know about `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`, I don't think this applies in this case.

How do I enable networking for my "command line" program?

Comment: Connection refused sounds like a server problem. Firewall? Port blocking of some kind. I don't think that's Android...

Comment: are you running wireshark?  you should run wireshark to actually see if the packet is getting out into the network...

Comment: Good idea! Let me check this.

Comment: I replaced the server with another one, written in node and it appears to be working. This is weird but it's not Android's fault. I'm an idiot :)

Comment: I believe the "shell" user has most of the useful permissions, including internet, so you can run basic network commands without needing to be root.  You can't really grant additional privileges without a rooted device -- apps launch from zygote, which has a full set, and drops privs as required when splitting into a new app.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out not to be Android's fault. This means that this question is invalid.

Comments explained everything.